# Can't add ThreeJS mesh to scene outside of scope - THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance

Tags: javascript, three.js, orbital-mechanics

I've just started using ThreeJS with the STLLoader, OrbitalControls and TransformControls modules.

When I add the mesh to my scene within the scope of the STLLoader function, it works as expected. When attempting to add it outside of the scope however, it throws the error **THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance**.

The mesh variable is declared globally so it doesn't make sense that I can't use it outside of the loader scope. Not sure what I am doing wrong but would appreciate any help!

```
var renderer, scene, camera, mesh, orbit, control;

                // mesh
                var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();

                loader.load( 'benchy.stl', function ( geometry ) {

                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x4eacc2, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );

                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                    mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0);
                    mesh.rotation.set( - Math.PI / 2, 0, 0 );
                    mesh.scale.set( 2, 2, 2 );

                    //scene.add( mesh );
                });

                //controls
                orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                orbit.update();
                orbit.addEventListener( 'change', render );

                control = new THREE.TransformControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                control.addEventListener( 'change', render );
                control.addEventListener( 'dragging-changed', function ( event ) {
                    orbit.enabled = ! event.value;
                } );

                scene.add( mesh );
                control.attach( mesh );
                scene.add( control );
```

Comment: Please note, the tag <[stl](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info)> is for C++ Standard Template Library

Comment: Ah thanks for the heads up, completely overlooked that on the tag description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STLLoader.load()` works asynchronously. Even if you declare the variable `mesh` globally, it is still `undefined` when `scene.add( mesh );` is executed in your code. So adding `mesh` to the scene graph inside the `onLoad()` callback is the most robust (and easiest) solution.

`three.js R108`

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense now. Currently I just have all of the code in an init() function as shown in several examples. Would it be better to just move it all over to onLoad() instead?

Comment: TBH, that depends. If you only load a single model, you can call your `init()` routine in `onLoad()`. If you load more stuff, it's probably better to trigger the loading requests in `init()` and manage the loading process via [THREE.LoadingManager](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager).